# Creating a Proxy Server in Java corrupts binary files

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, spark-java, proxy-server

I am trying to create a proxy server in java using [Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/).

I listed for any incoming request and send any incoming request to the target server via Apache Http Client.
I then transform the incoming request by coping the headers, status and text.

Now this is working pretty fine, except the binary files. The binary files such as fonts are corrupted. My code is :

```
private static void mapStatus(HttpResponse response, spark.Response res) {
    res.status(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}

private static void mapHeaders(HttpResponse response, spark.Response res) {     
    for (Header header : response.getAllHeaders()) {
        res.header(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }
}

private static String result(HttpResponse response) throws ParseException, IOException {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    return entity == null ? "" : EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
```

I suspect the issue is with the result() method as it treats all the responses as text. How ever I tried by coping the streams as is :

```
private static void extractResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if(entity == null)
            return;
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        copyStream(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
}
```

And the binary files are still bad.
WHat could be the issue here ?

[Complete Code Link](https://github.com/abhinavsayan/java-spark-proxy-server/blob/master/SparkProxy.java)

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to use byte arrays and copy manually.

Comment: I tried that. (2nd snippet in the question). No difference in output.

Comment: Are you sure that's what `IOUtils.copy()` is doing under the hood?  I meant *manually* copy with byte buffers.

Comment: Tried coping manually. Same results. Incase it helps here is the complete code : https://github.com/abhinavsayan/java-spark-proxy-server/blob/master/SparkProxy.java